# Angular Interpolation bizarre behaviour

Tags: angular, angular7

So I have your basic Angular 7.2.12 Component, but for some reason this Component is doing something weird.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-combo',
  template: '<p [attr.data]="attrb">Hello {{blah}} how are you?</p>'
})
export class ComboComponent implements OnInit {
  public blah: string = 'Bob';
  @Input() public attrb: string = 'Something';

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Now if I use this, the HTML that is being rendered in Browser is...

```html
<app-combo [test]="someprop">
  <p>Hello </p>
</app-combo>
```

Where everything including **and after** my binding is gone.

I've stepped through the code, and my public property is set, and I've tried a whole bunch of other public properties, including `@Input()` ones, but for what ever reason it's like there are no accessible public properties that the template uses.

What's even more crazy is that the HTML text that follows the interpolation is also missing!

All my other components have been working fine, it's just this one particular component that is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you see any errors on console?

Comment: i have created a stackblitz and it looks fine to me.https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-c2voan

Comment: Thanks for creating the stackblitz @Ashok, seems the issue was actually caused higher up to the bound attribute I was using was wrongly spelt, and thus missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the behaviour was a result of the passed `someprop` in the `test` binding in the HTML that was using my component didn't exist.

e.g....

```
<app-combo [test]="CORRECTLY_SPELT_VARIABLE">
```

Still can't explain why the trailing HTML **after** the handlebars didn't appear before, but after fixing the spelling of the name of the component's input to what it should have been, it all started working as expected.

The solution for this was found in the variable name being supplied to my component's input was missing (incorrectly spelt), and that the issue wasn't with my component, but the component calling it.